# Functional Testing tool

Tags: software-testing

Recommend some functional testing tool with the following requirements.

1. Easy to write testcases.
2. Ability to get client side performance metrics.
3. Ability to execute a function in client side.
4. Good reporting feature for testruns.
5. Good handling of waits.
6. Only opensource.
7. Easy to setup and bundle with any application.
8. Good community support.

I have explored a few. Selenium, testcafe etc. There are many other tools available. Which one will fit in these usecases.

I need to test a WebApplication on a browser and mobile app.

Comment: The suggested tools (Selenium) seems to suggest testing HTMl/JS/CSS, but the question does not even mention a programming language :-(

Comment: I would like to write testcases in JavaScript. Also is it possible to write testcases in JS in Selenium?

Comment: Please narrow your question, which platform is to be tested (Android apps/iphone apps/windows phone apps/windows desktop apps, etc)?

Comment: Also it is good to mention which language is preferred for writing tests.

Comment: I need to test a WebApplication on a browser and mobile app. Testcases in javascript preferably.